# When I catch an exception, how do I get the type, file, and line number?

Tags: python, exception, stack-trace, traceback

Catching an exception that would print like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/tmp.py", line 1, in <module>
    4 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I want to format it into:

```
ZeroDivisonError, tmp.py, 1
```

Comment: Use the built-in [traceback](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) module.

Comment: It may also be helpful to print line of code, where exception happened: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519177/python-exception-handling-line-number/20264059#20264059

Comment: None of these solutions find the line of code *where the exception happened*, @Apogentus. Maybe it's because it's Python 2 code or something but these solutions find the line of code much nearer where the exception is caught than where it was raised.

Answer (score 534, accepted):

```
import sys, os

try:
    raise NotImplementedError("No error")
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

Comment: You should be careful about unpacking sys.exc_info() into local variables, since if you get an exception in the except handler, the local vars could get kept in a circular reference and not GC'd.  Best practice is to always just use slices off of sys.exc_info() instead.  Or use other modules like traceback, as other posters have suggested.

Comment: is tb just exc_tb?
and os.path.split(blabla)[1] is os.path.basename(balbal)

Comment: With this code, I get (when `try: 1/0`) :
`<type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'> integer division or modulo by zero`. How to have `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero` instead ?

Comment: @Basj: With sys.exc_info()[0].__name__ you get the plain name of the type.

Comment: @DanielPryden Python docs are also using the same unpacking method https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples

Comment: I am importing a Class from a different file, when I use this solution the error points to the line in the current file on which the function from the class is called. The actual error occurs in a class file but this solution only shows the error in a current file. Any way to dig deeper?

Comment: @RobM: Yes, it's thread-safe. `sys.exc_info()` was introduced to deal with thread-safety problems in the previous API. Its output is specific to both the current thread and the current stack frame.

Comment: use logging.exception(e) if using logging lib

Comment: Is sys.exc_info() thread safe?

Comment: @DanielPryden's comment no longer applies in Python 3, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11414894/extract-traceback-info-from-an-exception-object#comment19173332_11417308

Answer (score 337):

Simplest form that worked for me.

```
import traceback

try:
    print(4/0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(4/0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: while not exactly the format the op wanted, this is the simplest and most robust solution

Comment: what is robust about it?

Comment: It just more robust. High rate answer can't print the deepest stack in my program.

Comment: you can also use `traceback.print_exc()`, without `print()`. save some typing :)

Answer (score 55):

[Source](http://jserv.sayya.org/misc/use_source_luke.png) (Py v2.7.3) for [traceback.format_exception()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8dffb76faacc/Lib/traceback.py#l130) and called/related functions helps greatly.  Embarrassingly, I always forget to [Read the Source](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UTSL.html).  I only did so for this after searching for similar details in vain. A simple question, "How to recreate the same output as Python for an exception, with all the same details?"  This would get anybody 90+% to whatever they're looking for.  Frustrated, I came up with this example.  I hope it helps others.  (It sure helped me!  ;-)

```
import sys, traceback

traceback_template = '''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%(filename)s", line %(lineno)s, in %(name)s
%(type)s: %(message)s\n''' # Skipping the "actual line" item

# Also note: we don't walk all the way through the frame stack in this example
# see hg.python.org/cpython/file/8dffb76faacc/Lib/traceback.py#l280
# (Imagine if the 1/0, below, were replaced by a call to test() which did 1/0.)

try:
    1/0
except:
    # http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info() # most recent (if any) by default

    '''
    Reason this _can_ be bad: If an (unhandled) exception happens AFTER this,
    or if we do not delete the labels on (not much) older versions of Py, the
    reference we created can linger.

    traceback.format_exc/print_exc do this very thing, BUT note this creates a
    temp scope within the function.
    '''

    traceback_details = {
                         'filename': exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename,
                         'lineno'  : exc_traceback.tb_lineno,
                         'name'    : exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_name,
                         'type'    : exc_type.__name__,
                         'message' : exc_value.message, # or see traceback._some_str()
                        }

    del(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback) # So we don't leave our local labels/objects dangling
    # This still isn't "completely safe", though!
    # "Best (recommended) practice: replace all exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback
    # with sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1], sys.exc_info()[2]

    print
    print traceback.format_exc()
    print
    print traceback_template % traceback_details
    print
```

In specific answer to this query:

```
sys.exc_info()[0].__name__, os.path.basename(sys.exc_info()[2].tb_frame.f_code.co_filename), sys.exc_info()[2].tb_lineno
```

Comment: change `'message' : exc_value.message` to `'message' : str(exc_value)` for py3

Comment: What's unsafe about letting Python handle those variables like any other variables?

Answer (score 52):

Here is an example of showing the line number of where exception takes place.

```
import sys
try:
    print(5/0)
except Exception as e:
    print('Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(e).__name__, e)

print('And the rest of program continues')
```

Answer (score 48):

Without any imports, but also incompatible with imported modules:

```
try:
    raise TypeError("Hello, World!")  # line 2
except Exception as e:
    print(
        type(e).__name__,          # TypeError
        __file__,                  # /tmp/example.py
        e.__traceback__.tb_lineno  # 2
    )
```

`$ python3 /tmp/example.py`
`TypeError /tmp/example.py 2`

To reiterate, this does **not** work across `import`s or modules, so if you do `import X; try: X.example();` then the filename and line number will point to the line containing `X.example()` instead of the line where it went wrong *within* `X.example()`. If anyone knows how to easily get the file name and line number from the last stack trace line (I expected something like `e[-1].filename`, but no such luck), please improve this answer.

Comment: I think possibly `e.__traceback__.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename` would do the trick for the filename.

Answer (score 46):

You could achieve this without having to import traceback:

```
try:
    func1()
except Exception as ex:
    trace = []
    tb = ex.__traceback__
    while tb is not None:
        trace.append({
            "filename": tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename,
            "name": tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_name,
            "lineno": tb.tb_lineno
        })
        tb = tb.tb_next
    print(str({
        'type': type(ex).__name__,
        'message': str(ex),
        'trace': trace
    }))
```

Output:

```
{

  'type': 'ZeroDivisionError',
  'message': 'division by zero',
  'trace': [
    {
      'filename': '/var/playground/main.py',
      'name': '<module>',
      'lineno': 16
    },
    {
      'filename': '/var/playground/main.py',
      'name': 'func1',
      'lineno': 11
    },
    {
      'filename': '/var/playground/main.py',
      'name': 'func2',
      'lineno': 7
    },
    {
      'filename': '/var/playground/my.py',
      'name': 'test',
      'lineno': 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to get the file name.

```
__file__.__str__
```

To sum it, I created a page to show errors. Return this on exception.

```
context={
                'details':'Type of error:{}:Function name:{}:Line number:{}'.format(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno),
                'error_details':str(e),
                'filename':__file__.__str__,
            })
```

How it looks in case an exception occurs:

[image]

Comment: FYI, copying the text instead of making a pixely (jpeg-y) screenshot of text is more searchable and useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    4/0
except Exception as exc:
    print("error: ",exc)
    print("error file info: ",exc.__traceback__.tb_frame)
    print("error line#: ",exc.__traceback__.tb_lineno)
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?