# When I catch an exception, how do I get the type, file, and line number of the previous frame?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278705/python-when-i-catch-an-exception-how-do-i-get-the-type-file-and-line-number/1278740#1278740), I'm now doing error handling one level down. That is, I call a function which calls another larger function, and I want where it failed in that larger function, not in the smaller function. Specific example. Code is:

```
import sys, os

def workerFunc():
    return 4/0

def runTest():
    try:
        print workerFunc()
    except:
        ty,val,tb = sys.exc_info()
        print "Error: %s,%s,%s" % (
            ty.__name__,
            os.path.split(tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1],
            tb.tb_lineno)

runTest()
```

Output is:

```
Error: ZeroDivisionError,tmp2.py,8
```

but line 8 is "print workerFunc()" - I know that line failed, but I want the line before:

```
Error: ZeroDivisionError,tmp2.py,4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a line:

```
    tb = tb.tb_next
```

just after your call to `sys.exc_info`.

See the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) under "Traceback objects".

Answer (score 3):

`tb.tb_next` is your friend:

```
import sys, os

def workerFunc():
    return 4/0

def runTest():
    try:
        print workerFunc()
    except:
        ty,val,tb = sys.exc_info()
        print "Error: %s,%s,%s" % (
            ty.__name__,
            os.path.split(tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1],
            tb.tb_next.tb_lineno)

runTest()
```

But the [traceback module](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html) does this and much more:

```
import traceback

def workerFunc():
    return 4/0

def runTest():
    try:
        print workerFunc()
    except:
        print traceback.format_exc()

runTest()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the bottom of the traceback, so you need to loop along until there are no more frames.  Do this to find the frame you want:

```
while tb.tb_next:
    tb = tb.tb_next
```

after sys.exc_info.  This will find the exception no matter how many call frames down it happened.