# In python, how to use traceback to assign the error message to a variable?

Tags: python, exception

```
import traceback  
try:  
   1/0  
except Exception,e:  
   traceback.print_exc()
```

The output is as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_traceback.py", line 3, in <module>
1/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

However I don't want to use `traceback.print_exc()` to print the output. Instead, I want to save the output to a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Related: [How to save traceback / sys.exc_info() values in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238360/how-to-save-traceback-sys-exc-info-values-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 4):

Use `traceback.format_exc()`:

```
import traceback

try:
   1/0
except Exception:
   trace = traceback.format_exc()
   print trace
```

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html):

> **traceback.format_exc([limit])**
>
> This is like print_exc(limit) but returns a string instead of printing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import traceback  
try:  
   1/0  
except Exception as e:  
   error = traceback.format_exc()


print(error)
```