# How to know what function throws the exception in Python

Tags: python, debugging

I have a python script over 2000 lines and it's through the below exception on the production server and I'm not able to reproduce the issue locally to debug it and I don't know where it comes from.

```
Exception TypeError: TypeError("argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable",) in <bound method Popen3.__del__ of <popen2.Popen3 instance at 0x7fccba7b65f0>> ignored
Exception TypeError: TypeError("argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable",) in <bound method Popen3.__del__ of <popen2.Popen3 instance at 0x7fccba7b62d8>> ignored
Exception TypeError: TypeError("argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable",) in <bound method Popen3.__del__ of <popen2.Popen3 instance at 0x7fccba824ef0>> ignored
Exception TypeError: TypeError("argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable",) in <bound method Popen3.__del__ of <popen2.Popen3 instance at 0x7fccba824f80>> ignored
```

Is there a way to make the interpreter print the trace for the exception as Java does? To be able to know what is throwing this exception.

Comment: ```from sys import exc_info```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238360/how-to-save-traceback-sys-exc-info-values-in-a-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`traceback.print_exc()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exc) in the `except` block:

```
try:
    1[0]  # raises
except TypeError:
    traceback.print_exc()
    raise
```