# Python exception handling - line number

Tags: python, exception, indexing

I'm using python to evaluate some measured data. Because of many possible results it is difficult to handle or possible combinations. Sometimes an error happens during the evaluation. It is usually an index error because I get out of range from measured data.

It is very difficult to find out on which place in code the problem happened. It would help a lot if I knew on which line the error was raised. If I use following code:

```
try:
    result = evaluateData(data)
except Exception, err:
    print ("Error: %s.\n" % str(err))
```

Unfortunately this only tells me that there is and index error. I would like to know more details about the exception (line in code, variable etc.) to find out what happened. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/print-the-full-traceback-in-python-without-halting-the-program!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples

Comment: @JeCh The answers look good.  Please accept one.  To accept it click the empty checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: The answer that is voted highest here is also presented in the stackoverflow question that @CharlesBeattie references above. That answer has important comments associated with it whereas this answer does not.  It's definitely worth your time to check that one out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When I catch an exception, how do I get the type, file, and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278705/when-i-catch-an-exception-how-do-i-get-the-type-file-and-line-number)

Answer (score 103):

Solution, printing filename, linenumber, line itself and exception description:

```
import linecache
import sys

def PrintException():
    exc_type, exc_obj, tb = sys.exc_info()
    f = tb.tb_frame
    lineno = tb.tb_lineno
    filename = f.f_code.co_filename
    linecache.checkcache(filename)
    line = linecache.getline(filename, lineno, f.f_globals)
    print 'EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj)


try:
    print 1/0
except:
    PrintException()
```

Output:

```
EXCEPTION IN (D:/Projects/delme3.py, LINE 15 "print 1/0"): integer division or modulo by zero
```

Comment: For my python 3.6.5 I needed to add parens to last line with print: print('EXCEPTION IN ({}, LINE {} "{}"): {}'.format(filename, lineno, line.strip(), exc_obj))

Comment: This gives you info on the first file in the stacktrace. But most times you want the last since that is where the error actually occurred.

Comment: How can we fetch last ? @reubano

Comment: @alper see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66416364/408556)

Comment: This doesn't report the line where the exception was raised, only where it was caught.

Answer (score 44):

To simply get the line number you can use `sys`, if you would like to have more, try the [traceback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module.

```
import sys    
try:
    [][2]
except IndexError:
    print("Error on line {}".format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno))
```

*prints*:

```
Error on line 3
```

---

[Example from the `traceback` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback-examples):

```
import sys, traceback

def lumberjack():
    bright_side_of_death()

def bright_side_of_death():
    return tuple()[0]

try:
    lumberjack()
except IndexError:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print "*** print_tb:"
    traceback.print_tb(exc_traceback, limit=1, file=sys.stdout)
    print "*** print_exception:"
    traceback.print_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback,
                              limit=2, file=sys.stdout)
    print "*** print_exc:"
    traceback.print_exc()
    print "*** format_exc, first and last line:"
    formatted_lines = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
    print formatted_lines[0]
    print formatted_lines[-1]
    print "*** format_exception:"
    print repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,
                                          exc_traceback))
    print "*** extract_tb:"
    print repr(traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback))
    print "*** format_tb:"
    print repr(traceback.format_tb(exc_traceback))
    print "*** tb_lineno:", exc_traceback.tb_lineno
```

Answer (score 30):

I use the `traceback` which is simple and robust:

```
import traceback

try:
    raise ValueError()
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())  # or: traceback.print_exc()
```

Out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catch.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise ValueError()
ValueError
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Others doesnt show error line correctly when error is inside function

Answer (score 16):

The simplest way is just to use:

```
import traceback
try:
    <blah>
except IndexError:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

or if using logging:

```
import logging
try:
    <blah>
except IndexError as e:
    logging.exception(e)
```

Answer (score 5):

Gives you file, lineno, and exception for the last item in the call stack

```py
from sys import exc_info
from traceback import format_exception


def print_exception():
    etype, value, tb = exc_info()
    info, error = format_exception(etype, value, tb)[-2:]
    print(f'Exception in:\n{info}\n{error}')

try:
    1 / 0
except:
    print_exception()
```

prints

```py
Exception in:
   File "file.py", line 12, in <module>
    1 / 0

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the python logging library, it has two useful methods that might help in this case.

1. logging.findCaller()

   - findCaller(stack_info=False) - Reports just the line number for the previous caller leading to the exception raised
   - findCaller(stack_info=True) - Reports the line number & stack for the previous caller leading to the exception raised
2. logging.logException()

   - Reports the line & stack within the try/except block that raised the exception

For more info checkout the api https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers already posted here that show how to get the line number, but it's worth noting that if you want variables containing the "raw data," so to speak, of the stack trace so that you can have more granular control of what you display or how you format it, using the `traceback` module you can step through the stack frame by frame and look at what's stored in the attributes of the frame summary objects. There are several simple and elegant ways to manipulate the frame summary objects directly. Let's say for example that you want the line number from the last frame in the stack (which tells you which line of code triggered the exception), here's how you could get it by accessing the relevant frame summary object:

### Option 1:

```
import sys
import traceback
try:
    # code that raises an exception
except Exception as exc:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    stack_summary = traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)
    end = stack_summary[-1]  # or `stack_summary.pop(-1)` if you prefer
```

### Option 2:

```
import sys
import traceback
try:
    # code that raises an exception
except Exception as exc:
    tbe = traceback.TracebackException(*sys.exc_info())
    end = tbe.stack[-1]  # or `tbe.stack.pop(-1)` if you prefer
```

---

In either of the above examples, `end` will be a frame summary object:

```
>>> type(end)
<class 'traceback.FrameSummary'>
```

which was in turn taken from a stack summary object:

```
>>> type(stack_summary)  # from option 1
<class 'traceback.StackSummary'>
>>> type(tbe.stack)  # from option 2
<class 'traceback.StackSummary'>
```

The stack summary object behaves like a list and you can iterate through all of the frame summary objects in it however you want in order to trace through the error. The frame summary object (`end`, in this example), contains the line number and everything else you need to locate where in the code the exception occurred:

```
>>> print(end.__doc__)
A single frame from a traceback.

    - :attr:`filename` The filename for the frame.
    - :attr:`lineno` The line within filename for the frame that was
      active when the frame was captured.
    - :attr:`name` The name of the function or method that was executing
      when the frame was captured.
    - :attr:`line` The text from the linecache module for the
      of code that was running when the frame was captured.
    - :attr:`locals` Either None if locals were not supplied, or a dict
      mapping the name to the repr() of the variable.
```

And if you capture the exception object (either from `except Exception as exc:` syntax or from the second object returned by `sys.exc_info()`), you will then have everything you need to write your own highly customized error printing/logging function:

```
err_type = type(exc).__name__
err_msg = str(exc)
```

---

### Putting it all together:

```
from datetime import datetime
import sys
import traceback


def print_custom_error_message():
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    stack_summary = traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)
    end = stack_summary[-1]

    err_type = type(exc_value).__name__
    err_msg = str(exc_value)
    date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%B %d, %Y at precisely %I:%M %p")

    print(f"On {date}, a {err_type} occured in {end.filename} inside {end.name} on line {end.lineno} with the error message: {err_msg}.")
    print(f"The following line of code is responsible: {end.line!r}")
    print("Please make a note of it.")


def do_something_wrong():
    try:
        1/0
    except Exception as exc:
        print_custom_error_message()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_something_wrong()
```

Let's run it!

```
user@some_machine:~$ python example.py
On August 25, 2022 at precisely 01:31 AM, a ZeroDivisionError occured in example.py inside do_something_wrong on line 21 with the error message: division by zero.
The following line of code is responsible: '1/0'
Please make a note of it.
```

At this point you can see how you could print this message for any place in the stack: end, beginning, anywhere in-between, or iterate through and print it for every frame in the stack.

Of course, the formatting functionality already provided by the `traceback` module covers most debugging use cases, but it's useful to know how to manipulate the traceback objects to extract the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this snippet

```
import sys, os

try:
    raise NotImplementedError("No error")
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

for different views and possible issues you can refer [When I catch an exception, how do I get the type, file, and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278705/when-i-catch-an-exception-how-do-i-get-the-type-file-and-line-number/1278740#1278740)

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions answer the OPs problem, however, if one is holding onto a specific error instance and the last traceback stack won't do it they will not suffice —a corner scenario example given below.

In this case, the magic attribute `__traceback__` of a raised exception instance may be used. **This is a system traceback object (exposed as `types.TracebackType`, see [Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html)) not the module**. This traceback instance behaves just one like would expect (but it is always nice to check):

```
from collections import deque
from typing import (List, )
errors: List[Exception] = deque([], 5)
    
def get_raised(error_cls: type, msg: str) -> Exception:
# for debugging, an exception instance that is not raised
# ``__traceback__`` has ``None``
    try:
        raise error_cls(msg)
    except Exception as error:
        return error

error = get_raised(NameError, 'foo')
errors.append(error)

error = get_raised(ValueError, 'bar')
errors.append(error)

try:
    raise get_raised(TypeError, 'bar')
except Exception as error:
    errors.append(error)
```

Now, I can check out the first error's details:

```
import types

traceback = errors[0].__traceback__  # inadvisable name due to module
line_no: int = traceback.tb_lineno
frame: types.FrameType = traceback.tb_frame
previous: Union[type(None), types.TracebackType] = traceback.tb_next
filename: str = frame.f_code.co_filename
```

The traceback's previous is None for the second error despite a preceding error as expected, but for the third wherein an error is raised twice it is not.

This below is just a test which makes no sense contextually. A case were it is useful if when an exception is raised in a view of a webapp (a 500 status kind of incident) that gets caught and stored for the admit to inspect akin to Setry.io (but for free). Here is a minimal example where the home page `/` will raise an error, that gets caught and the route `errors` will list them. This is using Pyramid in a very concentrated way (multifile is way better) with no logging or authentication and the error logging could be better for the admin to inspect similar to Sentry.io.

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from waitress import serve
from collections import deque
# just for typehinting:
from pyramid.request import Request
from pyramid.traversal import DefaultRootFactory
from pyramid.router import Router
import types
from typing import (List, )


def home_view(context: DefaultRootFactory, request: Request) -> dict:
    raise NotImplementedError('I forgot to fill this')
    return {'status': 'ok'}  # never reached.

def caught_view(error: Exception, request: Request) -> dict:
    """
    Exception above is just type hinting.
    This is controlled by the context argument in 
    either the ``add_exception_view`` method of config,
    or the ``exception_view_config`` decorator factory (callable class)
    """
    # this below is a simplification as URLDecodeError is an attack (418)
    request.response.status = 500 
    config.registry.settings['error_buffer'].append(error)
    #logging.exception(error) # were it set up.
    #slack_admin(format_error(error))  # ditto
    return {'status': 'error',  'message': 'The server crashed!!'}

def format_error(error: Exception) -> str:
    traceback = error.__traceback__  # inadvisable name due to module
    frame: types.FrameType = traceback.tb_frame
    return f'{type(error).__name__}: {error}' +\
           f'at line {traceback.tb_lineno} in file {frame.f_code.co_filename}'

def error_view(context: DefaultRootFactory, request: Request) -> dict:
    print(request.registry.settings['error_buffer'])
    return {'status': 'ok', 
            'errors':list(map(format_error, request.registry.settings['error_buffer']))
           }
    
with Configurator(settings=dict()) as config:
    config.add_route('home', '/')
    config.add_route('errors', '/errors')
    config.add_view(home_view, route_name='home', renderer='json')
    config.add_view(error_view, route_name='errors', renderer='json')
    config.add_exception_view(caught_view, context=Exception, renderer='json')
    config.registry.settings['error_buffer']: List[Exception] = deque([], 5)  
    # not in config.registry.settings, not JSON serialisable
    # config.add_request_method
    app  : Router = config.make_wsgi_app()

port = 6969
serve(app, port=port)
```

Answer (score 0):

I read all other answers and I see they just give you the outer line of error that is not useful at all. I guess you need the first line of code that raised the error in your code, and this is my solution:

```
import sys

def inner_func():
    i, j = 9, 0
    return  i / j


def outer_func():
    inner_func()


def main(args):
    outer_func()
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
    except Exception as exp:
        import traceback
        _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
        lineno = traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1].lineno  # the first inner line of error
        red, bold_red, normal = '\033[1;31m', '\033[0;31m', '\033[0m'
        err_msg = f'{red}line[{lineno}]: {bold_red}{exp}{normal}'
        print(err_msg, file=sys.stderr, sep='')
```

and the output is:

```
line[5]: division by zero
```