# Python: How to know which part is causing Error using try/except?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I want to use just one `try\except` for many variables. I want to find out which part is causing the error so I could print it to the user under the `except` part.

```
try:
    i = int(i)
    j = int(j)
    k = int(k)
    l = int(l)
    m = int(m)
    n = int(n)
    n+1 = int(n+1)
    ...
    ..
    .

except ValueError:

    print('Please enter an integer as {}'.format(# whether i, j, k, l, or ...))
```

I want to find out which `int(x)` is causing the error so I can print it to the user? Is there any way to do it? I don't want to try for each part because my variables are nearly infinite ;)

Comment: Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519177/python-exception-handling-line-number/20264059)

Comment: Why do you have all those variables in the first place? Your example here would appear to make them more fitting to be used as a list. (And in turn your error would be able to be pinpointed via the iterable that populates the list)

Comment: @Sayse, those are different tk entries, I want to know which is not int so I want to inform the user to input only integers!

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb I have read your suggestion but it's not what I expressed. I want to know for which input (i,j,k,...) the user is entering letters instead of ints. But thanx anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @rdas has a better answer, but since you didn't like it, you can do something like this as well, it just looks a little hacky and not that much better than doing `try/except` on every line.

```py
try:
    last = 'i'
    i = int('10')
    last = 'j'
    j = int('ten')
except ValueError:
    print(f'Please enter an integer as {last}')
```

Comment: As I have said i,j,k,l,... are all tk entry values of a Biiiig form and I want to know where the user is trying to input anything than an integer. So I can print it back under the `except` part. Is there any way to know which i,j,k,l,... is raising the `ValueError`? Thanx +1.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
def parse_int(num, name='var'):
    try:
        return int(num)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"Please enter an integer for {name}")


i = parse_int(i, name='i')
```

You can call the `parse_int` method for other variables as you see fit.

PS: you can't assign to an expression like `n+1` - that last line before the `except` in your code will not work

Comment: thank you. Yes I know `n+1` is wrong, I wrote it as extra clarification for what the problem is. Sorry but it's not exactly what I need. But thanx anyway.

Comment: This seems like the cleanest way to do it to me. Somehow you have to keep track of the object you are on.

Answer (score 1):

If all of them are integers, and if they are related in some way, then you can use a list to store them. The reason for another list with variable names is so you can use the same index to say which variable was error in.

```
my_list=[]
my_list_variables=["a","b","c"]
i=0
while True:
    try:
        x=int(input("Please input "+my_list_variables[i]+" : "))
        my_list.append(x)
        i=i+1
        #Just make sure to add a if statement to quit out of the loop
        #Like if that is end of the amount of input you are asking.
        break
    except ValueError:
        #index i doesn't change so you can tell the user which variable they
        #entered a wrong input for.
        print("Error: input "+my_list_variables[i]+" have to be a number")
```

Just have another list stored of name variables.