# How to display Python error location during runtime

Tags: python, runtime-error

Simple question but for some weird reason I cannot find the answer online.

For some error in a python script, i.e.:

```
$ python3 script.py
'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

How can I make it show where the error is being hit in my script (ex. line number, or the '^' thing), **without additional code**.

Comment: Do you have an example code to go with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python exception handling - line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519177/python-exception-handling-line-number)

Comment: For an uncaught exception, it normally will. What you're seeing is because you *do already* have "additional code" - a try/except block somewhere that is reporting the message from the caught exception, but not the traceback.