# Get error line number Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to debug python code, I want to pin point the line number in which error occurs. As per the posts found [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278705/python-when-i-catch-an-exception-how-do-i-get-the-type-file-and-line-number) the code gives the line no of the function being called. eg

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
            foo()
        except:
            <the code to print line no when error occurs>
```

But it gives me the line no of foo(),
Please help to find the exact line no in which error occurs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the third return value of sys.exc_info() they call exc_tb in your example. Instead of using exc_tb.tb_lineno, you can browse the traceback object using [traceback.extract_tb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html?highlight=traceback#traceback.extract_tb)(exc_tb). The repr look like :

```
*** extract_tb:
[('<doctest...>', 10, '<module>', 'lumberjack()'),
 ('<doctest...>', 4, 'lumberjack', 'bright_side_of_death()'),
 ('<doctest...>', 7, 'bright_side_of_death', 'return tuple()[0]')]
```

I suppose the line you are looking for is the last line of the structure. I haven't tested but this should do :

```
import sys, os, traceback

try:
    raise NotImplementedError("No error")
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    tb = traceback.extract_tb(exc_tb)[-1]
    print(exc_type, tb[2], tb[1])
```