# How to get filename of second item deep in exception traceback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, traceback

If I have a traceback such as:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\overall_input.py", line 5, in setup_data
    MODULE1.function_name()
  File "...\MODULE1.py", line 5, in function_name
    value = 1/0
```

How do I get the name of the second file deep - i.e. `MODULE1.py`?

For reference, I know I can get the first file (i.e. `overall_input.py`) by capturing the exception and then using:

```
exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
```

as described in the answer [Python When I catch an exception, how do I get the type, file, and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278705/python-when-i-catch-an-exception-how-do-i-get-the-type-file-and-line-number) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the same attributes after going towards the frame that raised the exception by using `tb_next` on `exc_tb`:

```
exc_tb.tb_next.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
```

`tb_next` is another `traceback` object that contains identical attributes as the previous; it's just a chain which you can follow until you reach the level you need.

---

Even though I've never used it, I'm certain the [`traceback` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) would be quite handy if you're doing weird things with them.