# Flask RestPlus: how to catch all exceptions and output the original error

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, flask-restplus

I'm trying to catch all exceptions that may happen and output the stack details as message in FlaskRestPlus.

The below is an example that works if I raise custom exception such as `RootException`. But I didn't manage to get it to work with `BaseException` or anything else that might serve as a catch all. I also didn't find a way to output the stack (or original error message) into the message body.

```
@api.errorhandler(RootException)
def handle_root_exception(error):
    return {'message': 'Here I want the original error message'}, 500
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve this would be highly appreciated. THe documentation doesn't seem to be entirely clear: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/errors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a generic error handler, you can use:

```
@api.errorhandler(Exception)
def generic_exception_handler(e: Exception):
```

## Stack Trace Capturing

To customize stack trace handling, see [Python When I catch an exception, how do I get the type, file, and line number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1278705/1164465).

#### Example stack trace data capture

```
import sys

...

@api.errorhandler(Exception)
def generic_exception_handler(e: Exception):
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()

    if exc_traceback:
        traceback_details = {
            'filename': exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename,
            'lineno': exc_traceback.tb_lineno,
            'name': exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_name,
            'type': get_type_or_class_name(exc_type),
            'message': str(exc_value),
        }
        return {'message': traceback_details['message']}, 500
    else:
        return {'message': 'Internal Server Error'}, 500
```

The function `get_type_or_class_name` is a helper that gets the type name of an object, or in the case of a Class, returns the Class name.

```
def get_type_or_class_name(var: Any) -> str:
    if type(var).__name__ == 'type':
        return var.__name__
    else:
        return type(var).__name__
```

It is also customary to provide an `HTTPException` handler:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException

@api.errorhandler(HTTPException)
def http_exception_handler(e: HTTPException):
```

Comment: @Nickpick See updated answer with definition of `get_type_or_class_name`.

Comment: This works great in debug mode, but it doesn't seem to work if it's in production mode (i.e. flask not in debug or run with iis). Any suggestions what I can do about that?