# Line number in Python exception

Tags: python, exception

How to get line number of exception in Python?
The output of the following code

```
try:
    print("a" + 1)
except Exception as error_message:
    print("There was an error: " + str(error_message))
```

is

```
There was an error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

But instead of just printing the

```
"There was an error: " + str(error_message)
```

how to print the line number as well like this example

```
try:
    print("a" + 1)
except Exception as error_message and linenumber as linenumber:
    print("There was an error: " + str(error_message) + ". The line where the code failed was " + str(linenumber))
```

with the expected output of

```
There was an error: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str. The line where the code failed was 2
```

This would be really useful for me when debugging my projects

Comment: I know there are similar question out there, but I couldn't find a solution by looking or trying them out.

Comment: You might want to look at the standard way of formatting tracebacks: https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html

Comment: use traceback module. U can try `traceback.print_tb(error_message.__traceback__)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import traceback

try:
    print("a" + 1)
except Exception as e:
    print("There was an error: " + e.args[0] + ". The line where the code failed was " + str(traceback.extract_stack()[-1][1]))
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: This doesn't work. It seems to report the line where the exception was caught, not where it was raised.

Comment: @NeilG just do traceback.print_exc()

Comment: That's what everyone says @SpicyCatGames. I don't know why everyone automatically thinks everyone wants to print to console. I don't. I want to capture the error information in my own structures so I can report it later.

Comment: @NeilG traceback.format_exc() will give you a string. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info

Comment: @SpicyCatGames, I want the separate pieces so I can manipulate them and apply custom formatting. I found the associated "duplicate" question referred to above provided better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278705/when-i-catch-an-exception-how-do-i-get-the-type-file-and-line-number