# try and except errors in tkinter + Geo API call

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling, python-requests

I am trying to get an entry where the user should enter a city. After I get the city I call an API to get some details which I later use for other widgets and data wrangling.

My problem is that I can't catch the various errors that are the result of the user not entering a valid city. I received some errors for TKinter and some for bad requests. I have tried to catch them with try and except, but they are still returned. My app does not crash or anything, but it is just annoying to receive these errors and not being able to clear them.

Below is my function and a screenshot of the errors. Any feedback is appreciated as to why they persist so much.

```
def get_city_and_place(self):
    """This function takes as input a string of a city name and
    returns in a dictionary the lat, lon, city name, and country code."""

    if self.marker_observer_on is False:  # if is not placed - create it and update marker status

        try:
            city = self.city_entry.get().strip().capitalize()
            tk_msg.showinfo(title="Enter a city", message="Please enter a city")

            geo_api_call = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q={city}&limit=1&appid={geo_api_key}"
            response = requests.get(f"{geo_api_call}")
            response.raise_for_status()
            data = response.json()

            lat = float(str(data[0]['lat'])[0:8])
            lon = float(str(data[0]['lon'])[0:8])

            self.city_params = {
                "city_lon": float(lon),
                "city_lat": float(lat),
                "city_name": data[0]['name'],
                "country": data[0]['country']
            }
            self.marker_observer = self.map_widget.set_position(lat, lon, marker=True)
            self.marker_observer.set_text(f"{self.city_params['city_name']},{self.city_params['country']}")
            self.marker_observer_on = True
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            raise SystemExit(e)

    else:
        # delete old labels and observation marker, then run again
        for label in self.labels:
            label.destroy()
        self.marker_observer.delete()
        self.marker_observer_on = False
        self.get_city_and_place()
```

This function on its own may be hard to work with, so feel free to delete anything extra so long as the errors can be caught.

[image]

Edit: I am thinking somehow to do this with the tkinter messagebox, but not sure where can it be implemented, and still I will need to be able to grab the errors when they occur.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're trying to catch the exception that is being thrown. You're trying to catch a `RequestException` but the error being thrown is a `HTTPError`.

Comment: Hi Bryan, I did try to catch HTTPError as well. Just the code example above is the last thing I tried before finally posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not catching all the error types you can catch `Exception` to catch all. But this is only recommended for debugging purposes. Following the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278705/when-i-catch-an-exception-how-do-i-get-the-type-file-and-line-number) you can format it like this in a print statement:

```py
import sys, os

try:
    # ...
except Exception as e:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
```

Now with the type, the file and the line wich caused the error you can then refine the error handling by enclosing the statements in seperate `try` blocks per error. This is usually recommended if you want to continue with a routine and need to correct something.